# tabletop_object_perception for electric

Tags: ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the repeat, but I want to ask a more general question related to this post: "[Problem installing tabletop_object_perception package](http://answers.ros.org/question/12175/problem-installing-tabletop_object_perception)".

Which tag or branch of tabletop_object_perception works with electric? Alternatively, which tag/branch is supposed to work with electric?

Thanks,
Sean

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31103/tabletop_object_perception-for-electric/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Everything in tabletop_object_perception has been moved to pr2_object_manipulation/perception for Electric.  Debs can be gotten by apt-getting ros-electric-pr2-object-manipulation .

For svn, Electric trunk is here:

https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_object_manipulation/branches/0.5-branch/perception

and exactly what's in Electric debs right now is here:

https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_object_manipulation/tags/electric/

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2